# How to ignore auto rotation when reading videos with ffmpeg python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, rotation

When reading a video with ffmpeg-python, if the video metadata contains a "rotate" attribute, it seems that by default ffmpeg transposes the incoming bytes according to the rotation value.

I would like to remove the automatic rotation. I tried the following, with no success:

```
import ffmpeg

process = (
        ffmpeg
        .input(filename)
        .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='yuv420p', loglevel=0, vsync='0')
        .global_args('-noautorotate')
        .run_async(pipe_stdout=True)
)
```

The code runs without any issue, but the rotation is not ignored, as I would have expected.

According to this:https://gist.github.com/vxhviet/5faf792f9440e0511547d20d17208a76, the noautorotate argument should be passed before input.

I tried the following:

```
process = (
        ffmpeg
        .global_args('-noautorotate')
        .input(filename)
        .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='yuv420p', loglevel=0, vsync='0')
        .run_async(pipe_stdout=True)
)
```

also with no success:

```
AttributeError: module 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'global_args'
```

Any suggestion?

EDIT

Passing noautorotate as kwargs does not work either (size of video after reading is 0)

```
    process = (
            ffmpeg
            .input(self.file, **{'noautorotate':''})
            .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='yuv420p', loglevel=1, vsync='0')
            .run_async(pipe_stdout=True)
    )
```

Comment: Add the option as an argument of `input()` call.

Comment: I get the following error: TypeError: input() takes 1 positional argument

Comment: Right, it must be passed in as a keyword argument. [Docs](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/#ffmpeg.input) read "Any supplied kwargs are passed to ffmpeg verbatim (e.g. t=20, f='mp4', acodec='pcm', etc.)."

Comment: thanks, i tried with .input(self.file, **{'noautorotate':''}), but for some reasons it does not read anything

Comment: What you might have is an opposite situation. The said metadata is telling video players to rotate to show its content properly (similar to EXIF image format) and the video is stored in "incorrect" rotation. Then, it ffmpeg's responsibility to show it in the correct orientation (look for `transpose` ffmpeg filter)

Comment: @gisk I recommend you to test your solution using FFmpeg CLI first (pipe the raw video to FFplay without from command line without Python). Example: `ffmpeg -noautorotate -i input.mkv -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p pipe: | ffplay -f rawvideo -video_size 192x108 -pixel_format yuv420p -i pipe:` (modify the resolution from 192x108 to the actual resolution). Read [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/578321/how-to-rotate-a-video-180-with-ffmpeg) for understanding the possible issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `**{'noautorotate':''}` with `**{'noautorotate':None}`.

Correct syntax:

```
process = (
        ffmpeg
        .input(self.file, **{'noautorotate':None})
        .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='yuv420p', loglevel=1, vsync='0')
        .run_async(pipe_stdout=True)
)
```

---

When using `**{'noautorotate':''}`, FFmpeg output an error:

> Option noautorotate (automatically insert correct rotate filters) cannot be applied to output url  -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.
> Error parsing options for output file .
> Error opening output files: Invalid argument

---

For testing we may add `.global_args('-report')`, and look at the log file.

Executing the following command:

```
process = (
    ffmpeg
    .input('input.mkv', **{'noautorotate':None})
    .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='yuv420p', vsync='0')
    .global_args('-report')
    .run_async()
    .wait()
)
```

The log file shows the built FFmpeg command line - looks correct:
`ffmpeg -noautorotate -i input.mkv -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -vsync 0 pipe: -report`

---

Executing the following command:

```
process = (
    ffmpeg
    .input('input.mkv', **{'noautorotate':''})
    .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='yuv420p', vsync='0')
    .global_args('-report')
    .run_async()
    .wait()
)
```

The log file shows the following built FFmpeg command line:
`ffmpeg -noautorotate  -i input.mkv -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -vsync 0 pipe: -report`

There is just an extra space before the `-i`, but for some reason FFmpeg interpret it as a URL (I think it might be a Unicode related issue - the empty strings is interpret as character that is not a space).

Comment: Thanks so much! Using None instead of '' works!